# Problem selecting values from option tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am scraping links from a dropdown menu like the following (with a bunch of stuff before and after)

```
                            <li class="selectyear">
                                <select id="years">
                                    
                                        <option selected="" value="/linkfor2020" "="">2020 Name
                                    
                                        <option value="/linkfor2010" "="">2010 Name
                                    
                                        <option value="/linkfor2009" "="">2009 Name
                                    
                                </select>
                                <button class="selectyear" aria-label="Choose Year">Go</button>                        
                            </li>
```

My code is as follows:

```
with open("data.html") as fp:
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
yearlist = soup.find("option",value=True)
for item in yearlist.find_all('option'):
    value=item.get('value')
    print value
```

However, it doesn't grab the 2020 link. The output is just the second two. Why is the first option being ignored?

Answer (score 0):

This HTML is incorrectly formatted. Option tags should have closing tags (`</option>`) but they're missing here. BeautifulSoup tries to parse it anyway, but it reads it this way:

```html
<li class="selectyear">
<select id="years">
  <option "="" selected="" value="/linkfor2020">2020 Name
    <option "="" value="/linkfor2010">2010 Name
      <option "="" value="/linkfor2009">2009 Name</option>
    </option>
  </option>
</select>
<button aria-label="Choose Year" class="selectyear">Go</button>
</li>
```

In other words, the `option`s are all nested. When you call `yearlist = soup.find('option')`, it finds the first, outermost option tag. When you the call `yearlist.find_all('option')`, it searches for all `option`s *within* the outer `option` tag, not including the original outer tag. This is desired behavior: we're searching for children of the given tag, so we shouldn't return the parent tag in the results.

You can get your list of all three `option`s by just doing `soup.find_all('option')`. Or if that returns other `option`s you don't want, you can do `soup.find('select', id='years').find_all('option')` instead.